# Coding to an interface an issue in using Hibernate ORM with Panache

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-panache

When using hibernate in spring generally we code to an interface like below

```java
public interface UserRepository {
    Collection<User> findByLastName(String lastName) throws DataAccessException;
    //more methods
}

@Repository
public class JpaUserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Collection<User> findByLastName(String lastName) {
        Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT user FROM User user  WHERE user.lastName LIKE :lastName");
        query.setParameter("lastName", lastName + "%");
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
..
}
```

How do we do the same in Panache?

```java
public interface UserRepository extends PanacheRepositoryBase<User, Integer> {

    Collection<User> findByLastName(String lastName) ;
    //more methods
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class JpaUserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Collection<User> findByLastName(String lastName) {
        Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT user FROM User user  WHERE user.lastName LIKE :lastName");
        query.setParameter("lastName", lastName + "%");
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

It throws

```
[2] Unsatisfied dependency for type javax.persistence.EntityManager and qualifiers [@Default]
        - java member: org....repository.jpa.JpaUserRepositoryImpl#em
        - declared on CLASS bean [types=[org....repository.jpa.JpaUserRepositoryImpl, org....repository.UserRepository, io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheRepositoryBase<org.....model.User, java.lang.Integer>, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.....repository.jpa.JpaUserRepositoryImpl]
[
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your life a bit easier:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserRepository implements PanacheRepository<User, Integer> {

   public List<User> findByLastName(String lastName) {
       return list("lastName", lastName);
   }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class UserService {
    @Inject
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public List<User> findByLastName(String lastName) {
        return userRepository.findByLastName(lastName);
    }
}
```

With Panache you don't really need to work with this repository pattern (although you can). The way I like to work now is like this:

```
@Entity
// Because you have defined your own ID (Integer), you should extend PanacheEntityBase. If you don't have a specific reason for defining a custom ID, I'd recommend to extend PanacheEntity, you'll get a Long ID for free.
public class User extends PanacheEntity {
    public String lastName;
    
    public static List<User> findByLastName(String lastName) {
        return list("lastName", lastName);
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class UserService {
    @Transactional
    public List<User> findByLastName(String lastName) {
        return User.findByLastName(lastName);
    }
}
```

Notice that when you use the PanacheEntity pattern you should define all instance fields as "public". Panache wraps those fields, so you will keep the encapsulation you need! (So if you define a custom setter for this field, the setter will be called when someone does:

```
user.lastName = "VanderLastName";
```

I have to admit that it took me a while to get used to it. So especially when you don't want to much change from what you're used to (Spring), you'd probably be better off implementing the Repository pattern. The good thing: it's completely your own choice!

The Quarkus documentation: https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache

Comment: In PersonService you are doing User.findByLastName but usually we call methods on the repository right?

Comment: my question is more towards if I need to do the repository pattern how do I do it in panache

Comment: I've added an example to my answer. For the repository pattern you'd need an instance (bean) of the UserRepository. You can than call the findByLastName method on the userRepository.
In my answer you find two exapmles: one with the repositoryPattern and one without. In Quarkus Panache the second method is the standard way. The repositoryPattern way is there because people are used to it :-P.